# F# Array.findindex

Tags: arrays, indexing, f#

I am pretty new to F# and am having a few issues debugging some code. The following piece of code creates a matrix which contains positional indices. I have two arrays both contain strings; one array is brought in off a .CSV, the other is hard coded.

`indexmatrix= Matrix |> Array.map (fun (j, _) -> load |> Array.findIndex (fun x -> x=j))`

I am getting the error of: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException, which implies that a match cannot be found, according to F# when I hover over the function. Could the issue be that the values are not stored correctly in the CSV? Or something I am not thinking of?

Thanks

Comment: what's this suppose to do?

Comment: Create a matrix which contains positional index

Comment: main problem is simply understanding the error

Comment: if I hover over the function the function it is explained: returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the predicate. Raise keynotfound if none of the elements satisfy predicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a *working* example:

```
let Matrix = [| (0,0); (1,0); (2,0)|]
let load = [| 0; 1; 2 |]
let indexMatrix =
  Matrix 
  |> Array.map (fun (j, _) ->
                  load 
                  |> Array.findIndex (fun x -> x = j))

// val indexMatrix : int [] = [|0; 1; 2|]
```

And break it by removing a required value from `load` array:

```
let load = [| 0; 2 |] // missing the corresponding 1
let indexMatrix =
  Matrix 
  |> Array.map (fun (j, _) ->
                  load 
                  |> Array.findIndex (fun x -> x = j))
```

Which will throw the `KeyNotFoundException`:

> `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: Exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' was thrown.`
>
> Could the issue be that the values are not stored correctly in the CSV?

Possibly, but ultimately what this means is there are tuples in `Matrix` whose first items have no corresponding values in `load`, which is why the `Array.findIndex` call throws. In order for this code to work, `load` must contain a value equal to the first item in every tuple in `Matrix`.